# where/how does usbip store host, remote port and remote busid

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, usb

@rodrigo
Good morning,
I have an usbip issue, I tried to integrate usbip in an initramfs-hook. Loading the kernel modules ubsip-core, vudc, usbip-host and hwadata makes it work but still gives an error. After connecting the host usb, which is absolutly fine to use there comes:

usbip: error: record connection

usbip port also give a similiar error:

libusbip: error: fopen
libusbip: error: read_record
.
.
9-1 -> unknown host, remote port and remote busid

It seems like there is a problem with rights management, but I´m unsure where these values (host, usbip_port_string, busid, rhport) even stored. Googleing some months brought me to this site and I saw the error was mentioned in another question. Cause it is a longer script I want to stop it if an error occurs so I really want to fix it. But to be honest I don't even understand the problem. Do you have a hint in which file these values are set or why these file is locked for a kernel module?

At another question I found these source code:

```
static int attach_device(char *host, char *busid)
{
int sockfd;
int rc;
int rhport;

// creates a TCP connection to the specified host on the specified port.
sockfd = usbip_net_tcp_connect(host, usbip_port_string);
if (sockfd < 0) {
    err("tcp connect");
    return -1;
}

// sends a query to the connected host to import the device specified by "busid".
rhport = query_import_device(sockfd, busid);
if (rhport < 0)
    return -1;

// closes the previously established TCP connection.
close(sockfd);

// records details of the connection, such as the host and port, the busid of the device and the
assigned rhport.
rc = record_connection(host, usbip_port_string, busid, rhport);
if (rc < 0) {
    err("record connection");
    return -1;
}

return 0;
}
```

from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/usb/usbip/src/usbip_attach.c

But for me it is not clear if these values are stored in a file or not. And if they are not what permission to set.
I really want to thank anybody who is posting anything constructive.

Answer (score 0):

it seems there's no files managed in this piece of code, and I don't think that there are any reference in these functions parameters, so i think that values are stored in a repository or in the heap memory (to be sure you should read the data structures of the funcions). For the permissions it depends by what is your goal, but in this piece of code i would say only read permissions beacouse funcions seems only to be "reading" functions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).